# jQuery template accessing field using value from another field

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

in jquery template, how can I access a variable based on the value in another variable?

for example, I render a jquery template using the following parameter:

```
var inputParams = {
    fieldName: 'field1',
    field1: 'abc',
    field2: 'efg',
    field3: 'ijk',
};
```

In my template, I want to dynamically render the template based on the value inside fieldName. To be specific, I want to render 'abc' using only fieldName. Is this possible?

Inside a jquery template, I know I can render values like so:

```
${fieldName}
${field1}
${field2}
...
```

But I am not so sure how to render 'abc' from fieldName. The following does not work:

```
${field1[${fieldName}]}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: To make this more clear, I'm talking about "jQuery template", not jQuery, and I'm not wrapping my variables inside jQuery. For those of you who do not know what jQuery template is, you can find the introduction here:

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this with jquery template:

```
${$data[fieldName]}
```

which does the job.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the *value* of an *existent key* in your object as an *access key* for a different *property*

What you can do here is simple calling the object using square brackets and use the propertyname to identify the other key.

```
var o = { test: 'mykey', mykey: 1 };
console.log(o[o.test]); // => prints 1
```

For you this would be:

```
inputParams[inputParams.fieldName]
```

You can use this notation everywhere you want as long as you have access to your `inputParams` object.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear what I'm asking. Your answer is not what i'm looking for. Thanks!